# How do I append something to the end of several classless divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my body I have several divs that contain one paragraph. I am trying to add a dashed line at the end of each div without adding or changing anything in the body. How do I target these divs to append the line?

The divs just look like: div p text /p /div

As requested here is the full page I am working on: http://pastebin.com/8DFBxfDw

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `jQuery` you can do

```
$('div').append('<hr>')
```

Or you can use a CSS trick and use an `::after`

```
div::after{
   content: '';
   border-bottom: 2px dashed #000;
   position: absolute;
   left: 0px;
   right: 0px;
   bottom: 0px;
}
```

the `::after` selector may not work in all browsers, so you will need to use a polyfill for older browsers.  http://caniuse.com/css-gencontent

Answer (score 0):

On the limited information you provide, I'd suggest:

```
$('div p:only-child').parent().css('border-bottom', '2px dashed #000');
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/W2776/).

With pure CSS, however:

```
div > p:last-child {
    border-bottom: 2px dashed #f00;
}

div > p + p:last-child {
    border-bottom-width: 0;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/W2776/1/).

References:

- CSS

  - [`:only-child` pseudo-class](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/#the-only-child-pseudo).
- jQuery

  - [`css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/).
  - [`parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/).

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div').each(function(index, value){
    $(this).append('---');
}
```

But a CSS approach would probably be best practice here with the limited amount of information you provided.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps in CSS instead of JavaScript considering you don't want to add anything to the body:

```
#faq div { border-bottom: 1px dashed; }
```

If you don't want the last div to have a line:

```
#faq div + div { border-top: 1px dashed; }
```